# React: How to pass data and methods to hierarchically organized components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parameter-passing, react-context, react-component

i have a page with components distributed by layers as follow:

I have a main page that contains several components and which in turn contains other components. Each level of the parent-child hierarchy I call a layer.

I separate these components into 3 types, reusable, coupled and modal:

- **Reusable** - Receive data by props and do what they need to. They can be reused in any context (page) because they are not coupled.
- **Coupled** - They are bound to the context (page) and can receive data by props or fetch data via API request.
- **Modal** - It is the last layer of the layers, however they are decoupled and receive the data and methods of the actions they need to perform.

The flow I run today is to get the main data when entering the page, then I pass the data via props to the respective components, as the user accesses it.

In some cases, due to the amount or sensitivity of the data, I request more data inside the coupled component, when the client accesses a higher level of detail.

And finally, I pass the data and methods to be executed in the last layer (modal components). There are scenarios where the method is created on the 1st layer (page) and only executed on the last layer (modal).

---

Based on this context above, what would be the most efficient way to pass data and methods to components?

Currently I pass via props, however, I still have doubts if this would be the best way or using ContextAPI.

Comment: It all depends on your code and what you want to achieve. Prop drilling might work on some cases, having a single source of truth via context api might be feasible when the layer depth increases

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you @kanuos !

After many time thinking about it, I'm using 3 options.
But which one do I choose? As @kanuos sad, depends!!

These are the 3 options I have and use:

1. **Continue using Props Drilling** - Some cases is necessary.
2. **Use Context** - It works well to avoid a lot of prop drilling.
3. **Composition** - Sometimes I want to avoid a lot of prop drilling and I also don't want to maintain a context dependency. In this case using the composition pattern I can directly pass the
   properties to what I want.